# janusgraph : creating a label for a small amount of data

Tags: janusgraph

I would like to use janusgraph to store a small amount of data (i.e. : 30 nodes) along with a larger graph (i.e. many millions nodes).

If I just use a distinct label, I will not be able to fetch the 30 nodes efficiently because node labels are not indexed, and it would need a full scan of the graph to find them. I could use an index and a fake property, but it seems to me that it would be overkill (and wrong design).

What would be the best way to achieve that ?

Comment: Are the two graphs disconnected ? If yes you can consider creating two different graph instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we abonned the idea. If we create an index there is a risk of having hot keys, and if we create another graph for that will be a little overkill in my opinion.

We will just simply put that data in another database (probably a relational database).